# backbone router won't work

Tags: backbone.js, meteor, router

So I have a Backbone router table like this :

```
var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes: {
":roles_id": "main",
":edit/:roles_id_editInfos": "edit",
":changepass/:id_user": "changepass"
},
main: function (list_id) {
var oldList = Session.get("roles_id");
if (oldList !== list_id) {
  Session.set("roles_id", list_id);
  Session.set("roles_id_editInfos", null);
  Session.set("id_user", null);
}
},
 edit: function (list_id, list_id2) {
var oldList = Session.get("roles_id_editInfos");
if (oldList !== list_id) {
  Session.set("roles_id_editInfos", list_id2);
  Session.set('roles_id', null);
  Session.set("id_user", null);
}
},
 changepass: function (list_id3, list_id4) {
 var oldList = Session.get("id_user");
  if(oldList !== list_id3){
    Session.set('id_user', list_id4);
    Session.set('roles_id', null);
    Session.set("roles_id_editInfos", null);
}
},
setList: function (list_id) {
this.navigate(list_id, true);
}
});

Router = new TodosRouter;

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

And for some reason when I click on the link -> '/changepass/{{_id}}' it's doesn't work.
But when I click on the other it's work, and if I delete the 'edit' route, for example, the 'changepass' route work.

The Backbone router have a limit of route ?

Can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes: {
":roles_id": "main",
":edit/:roles_id_editInfos": "edit",
":changepass/:id_user": "changepass"
},
```

why are you using colons before your routes path?

Comment: OK you alright but when I delete the colons nothing work ! ^^